# How to Auto adjust Scroll height of tab render items in native base react-native

Tags: react-native, tabs

I am using native base tabs to display scrollable tab bars in react-native
I had 4 tabs and the content in each render item tab changes, so the length of the tab bar content changes. how can I adjust the height of the scroll view based on content in tabview. it should not scroll when content is less. it leaves blank space below when content is less.

**when content in tab bar render item is more than the screen height it scrolls.**

[image]

**when content in tab bar render item is less than the screen height it should not scroll.**

**even if the content in the 2nd tab is less it scrolls based on height of 1st tab content height.**

[image]

**It should not scroll if the content on in tab render item is less.It should scroll based on the content in tab view**

Answer (score 0):

it's the sole reason why i left `native-base` because of the issue. It's and open issue with native base  and they havent resolved it yet. The problem is that i had 3 tabs and three scrollViews had different height. so it takes the longest height and when we go to any other tab , it leaves blank space.

this is the link to the open issue in github [native base tabs](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/1501#issuecomment-525666367) . Do check it out if you can find any resolution for it. I couldnt find it so ive switched to

[react native tab view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-tab-view) . .This is a better library  for tabs and coz of the issue in native abse. i switched to it.

Hope it helps. Feel free for doubts

Comment: ok thank you, I will try react-native-tab-view, is there any other way to show scrollable tab bars in both ios and android.

Comment: thats what ive used.  its for both android and ios. :)

Comment: and if you odnt want any library , you can always use scrollVIew and make your own component ,

Comment: do upvote if you found the response helpful. thanks :)

Comment: i tried the module works fine but can we render icons in react-native-tab-view, how can we do that

Comment: I am facing same issue height is not adjusted automatically, when content is less but it scrolls and leaves bank screen.

Comment: so what now i would suggest is making your custom view component with 3 scrollView,  using any library wont suffice your requirements